# Retrieve customer object Google Ads API

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api

I'm using the Google Ads REST API to retrieve a list of customers and display them to the user. I want to display these customers alongside metadata like the account name, whether  it's a manager account or not, etc.

I've already got a list of accessible customers using `https://googleads.googleapis.com/v15/customers:listAccessibleCustomers`. However, I can't find the appropriate documentation for retrieving the [customer object](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/rest/reference/rest/v15/Customer) itself using the customer id.

I've tried using the `https://googleads.googleapis.com/v15/customers/{customerID}/operations/get` endpoint, however this always returns a 404 resource not found error.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of searching, I've found you can retrieve attributes of a Google Ads customer using the following POST endpoint.

`https://googleads.googleapis.com/v15/customers/${accountID}/googleAds:search`

In the request body, specify the attributes you'd like to query using Google Ads query language in the `query` field.

For example:

```
// Define the request body
const requestBody = {
    query: 'SELECT customer.id, customer.resource_name, customer.descriptive_name, customer.manager, customer.test_account FROM customer'
};

// Make the request
axios.post(`https://googleads.googleapis.com/v15/customers/${CUSTOMER_ID}/googleAds:search`, requestBody, {
    headers: {
        "developer-token": {{DEVELOPER_TOKEN}}, // Replace with your developer token
        Authorization: `Bearer {{ACCESS_TOKEN}}`, // Replace with your access token
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },

})
```

You can find a full list of customer attributes [here](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v15/customer)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the REST API aspect, but if you can use the service [GoogleAdsService.Search](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v16/overview), you can get account level info using the following GAQL query:

```
SELECT 
customer_client.id, 
customer_client.level, 
customer_client.manager, 
customer_client.resource_name, 
customer_client.descriptive_name, 
customer_client.client_customer, 
customer_client.applied_labels, 
customer_client.currency_code, 
customer_client.hidden, 
customer_client.status, 
customer_client.test_account, 
customer_client.time_zone 
FROM customer_client
```

You can check the [customer_client](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v14/customer_client) documentation, or the [query builder](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v14/customer_client_query_builder) tool to see other options. Let me know if I can help with any further details.

```
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/account-management/get-account-hierarchy
```